# json.dump() creates file with "\n" instead of new line

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write to a json file using `json.dump`. Everything is fine but the output data looks like this `"{\n    \"AWSTemplateFormatVersion\": \"2010-09-09\",\n    \"Description\": \"ding dong\"}`

Instead of printing it in new lines. I've added `indent=4` and `separators=(',', ':')` but doesn't seem to help.
Here's my code

```
with open(TopicName+'.json', 'w') as json_file:
 json.dump(dict_file, json_file,sort_keys=False,indent=4, separators=(',', ':'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the file? It seems that the issue is with displaying the file contents, not the file itself.

Comment: `\n` is a newline. Do you want to get `\r\n` instead? E.g., Windows-style line endings?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want it to actually create a new line instead of writing `\n`. I tried opening in different editors but all of them open it as `\n` not a new line

Answer (score 0):

I just checked with your code and it actually writes as you wanted.
Probably it's a problem with your editor - check encoding if you use sublime or so.